# Sets of k expressions, being k a variable

Tags: list-manipulation, subscript

I need to write something like

Table[Subscript[A,i] = i, {i,5}]

in order to define a set of expressions. All is OK with this, but if I try to left the number of expressions as a variable k...

Table[Subscript[A,i] = i, {i,k}]

... Mathematica doesn't allow that. ¿It is possible to write this kind of k-sized sets of expressions?

Comment: First note `Subscript[A,i] = i` is not an equation but an affectiation (`=` is `Set`, not `Equal`). Is this really what you want?

Comment: I think your aim will be achieved simply by `Subscript[A,i_]:=i`. Then you get it valid for any `i`. Another story is that this is not an equation in Mathematica. If the expression `Subscript[A,i]=i` is not an equation in itself, but you simply use the expression  `Subscript[A,i]` somewhere in your code later, this may answer your need.

Comment: OK, forget then the word "equation", and think on "expression" instead. I need to have this set of expressions, from 1 to k.

Answer (score 2):

```
newA[k_] := Table[i, {i, k}]
A = newA[5]  (* {1,2,3,4,5} *)
A[[1]]  (* 1 *)
```

Subscripts are possible too, but it's a bad idea.  Use indexing.